# Avoiding recursion when setting exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I'm trying to do something relatively simple - to take the OrderedDict class and give it the ability to look up values based on integers or slices. So if I have the following

```
from collections import OrderedDict

test_dict = OrderedDict()
test_dict['a'] = 'value a'
test_dict['b'] = 'value b'
test_dict['c'] = 'value c'

test_dict[:2]
```

It would ideally give the result

```
['value a','value b']
```

To do this, I'm trying to subclass OrderedDict and then over-ride its **getitem** method. What I have is the following:

```
class indexed_dict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return list(self)[key]
        except TypeError: # Because we've entered a number instead of a key
            return self[key]
```

The trouble with this is that if you try to use it normally - say, `test_indexed_dict['a']` - the interpreter starts recursing away, presumably because the except clause asks it to run **getitem** again. Is there a better method of error handling which doesn't create this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Aran_Fey's answer, you need to check values in first `try` , so function would be:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    try:
        return list(self.values())[key]
    except TypeError:
        return super().__getitem__(key)
```

And whole class:

```
class IndexedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return list(self.values())[key]
        except TypeError:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
```

Nothing can be added to @Netwave's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the type of `key`, and also just return the slice over the **values** of the dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class IndexedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if type(key) is slice:
          return list(self.values())[key]
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/BetterSpeedyPixels)

Answer (score 1):

When you do `self[key]`, you're calling your own `__getitem__` method again. That causes endless recursion. What you want to do is to call your *parent class's* `__getitem__` method:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    try:
        return list(self)[key]
    except TypeError: # Because we've entered a number instead of a key
        return super().__getitem__(key)
```

Comment: But... `test_dict[:2]` returns `['a', 'b']`, not `['value a', 'value b']`